# Javascript: Editing a variable inside an object using callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I have this file `config.js`:

```
module.exports = function (cb) {
    this.config = {
        test: 4
    }
    return this.config;
}
```

I get it from `option.js`:

```
var Config = require('./config.js');

new Config(function (config) {
    var a = config.test;
}
```

Now the question: How can change the value of `test` in `config.js`? I want it to be `5`, not `4`. Tried `config.test = something`, didn't work.

Comment: Change the actual file, or just change the variable inside option.js? Start by calling the `cb()` function perhaps

Comment: What is  the best way to change the variable? Don't want to change actual file for now.

Comment: `return this;` instead of `return this.config;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need use a callback function, then you must call it, in your `config.js` file you aren't calling the function callback.

You can call the function callback and editing the value of `config.test` in this way:

```
module.exports = function (cb) {
        this.config = {
        test: 4
    }
    cb(this.config);
}
```

and the instantiation of your new Config object in this way:

```
var Config = require('./config.js');

new Config(function (config) {
    config.test++; // or any operation that you consider propertly
});
```

so you get a new Config object with config.test = 5

But you must remember that you don't modifying the real (hardcoded) value of `this.config.test` in place of that you're creating a new instance object of type Config.

Maybe you don't really need a function callback instead you can create a not hardcoded function constructor in this way in your `config.js` file

```
module.exports = function (test) {
    this.config = {
        test: this.test
    }
}
```

then you can create your object and pass any test value that you need in your other file

```
var Config = require('./config.js');
new Config(5);
```

I hope this can help you.